# How to change the first value in a dataframe that meets a certain condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe called `path` and want to change the **first** value of `Segment_code` from NaN to 0 where `IsPaused` is equal to 0. I am attempting to do this using:

`path[path['IsPaused']==0].head(1)['Segment_code'] = 0`

But I still have

```
>>> path[path['IsPaused']==0].head(1)['Segment_code']
37   NaN
Name: Segment_code, dtype: float64
```

Is there a different way to reassign the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You may find the index where 'IsPaused' equals zero for the first time and then readjust the value for Segment Code.

```
index_zero = path[path['IsPaused]==0].index[0]
path.iloc[index_zero, #number of column for SegmentCode] = 0
```